# When your computer is in sleep mode, can you make it so python runs?

Tags: python, sleep

After a certain amount of time, my windows computer goes into sleep mode. I am currently using PowerShell to run multiple programs in succession. I do not want to change the settings so the computer doesn't go to sleep. I want to find a way in which when the computer goes to sleep, PowerShell continues to run the python codes in the background. This way, I can also keep my computer locked if I am not at home. The reason I want to do this is that I need to produce a lot of data and plots in a short amount of time.

Comment: no. If you get hit over the head and fall uncouncious you can not code either. Only thing to do would be to simulate something that hinders your computer to go to sleep.

Comment: There are multiple different states of power management in modern computers. In all states that suspend the main operations of all CPUs running Python code is impossible. On the other hand power management in recent systems is very complex and you might be able to get your system into a low consumption state without suspending the CPU. Depending on the system and the OS of cause.

Comment: So you are saying that I can make my battery usage very low without making my computer going to sleep. How would I solve the problem of making my computer locked?

Comment: Setting up your machine for minimal power compunction is not a programming topic and off-topic for SO. You might find help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your computers "Power Options" in the Control panel. 
You don't need to worry about the screen locking because as long as the computer doesn't get put to sleep, your process should continue to run. However, if your system is set to sleep after a set amount of time you may need to change this to Never. Keep in mind there are separate settings depending on whether or not the system is plugged in.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that, but then if I keep it running it uses extra battery.

Comment: even the accepted answer is not correct. The execution of the code will be suspended when you go on sleep. it will resume back once your computer becomes active.

Comment: Ok, I think I have my answer. When the computer turns the display off, you have to put the password in to unlock the computer, and it also uses less energy. I can do this by changing the settings in the power options part of the control panel. Thank you.